# Javascript: image does not load on canvas

Tags: javascript, events, canvas

I am trying to use an image as the background of my canvas. However, I have a hard time to make the image load -- it always shows as blank:

```
<html> 
<script>
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "img/map.png";
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    

    window.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    } 
</script> 
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"> </canvas>

</body> 
</html>
```

However, if I put the following two lines into the window.onload function, then the image loads without any issue. what causes this issue? As I will use canvas and ctx in other functions, I really want to define them globally rather than individually define them in each function.

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can still use them globally. As canvas is not available immediately you are not able to draw picture before on load.

```
<script>
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "img/map.png";
    var canvas;
    var ctx ;  

    window.onload = function() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");    
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
    } </script>
```

Comment: Do not wait for the window's onload event, it won't wait for your image. Instead use `background.onload = function...`.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** The first option is to declare the canvas and context and assign them values after the document has [loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Onload</title>
    <script>
        const background = new Image();
        background.src = "img/map.png";
        let canvas;
        let ctx;

        window.onload = function() {
            canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Method One</h1>
    <p>Defined variables globally and assign then after the load event is fired</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**2)** The second method would be to put the script block after the canvas element so that it is already loaded in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) when your javascript tries to access it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Onload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Method Two</h1>
    <p>Put the script after the DOM element you wish to access</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <script>
        const background = new Image();
        background.src = "img/map.png";
        const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        window.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've used the new `const` and `let` keywords just to highlight the difference between these two approaches, although using `var` instead will work fine too. (see [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const))

If you want to [avoid global variables](https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals) then you might structure your code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Onload</title>
    <script>
        const background = new Image();
        background.src = "img/map.png";

        draw = context => {
            context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            draw(ctx);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Refactor</h1>
    <p>Add an event listener and pass in context to draw function</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't matter that I'm using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), or [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), I just prefer these newer methods. The point is to pass in the canvas context to any function that needs it `draw(ctx)`.

The two lines of code creating the `Image()` and then setting the background had to be done before the document had finished loading, this is a bit of a fudge. What we really need to do is make sure that the image we are trying to set as the background has loaded before calling `drawImage()` [Using images](http://**1)**%20The%20first%20option%20is%20to%20declare%20the%20canvas%20and%20context%20and%20assign%20them%20values%20after%20the%20document%20has%20[loaded][1]%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Chtml%20lang=%22en%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EOnload%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20background%20=%20new%20Image();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background.src%20=%20%22img/map.jpg%22;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20canvas;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20ctx;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.onload%20=%20function()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20canvas%20=%20document.getElementById(%22myCanvas%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ctx%20=%20canvas.getContext(%222d%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ctx.drawImage(background,%200,%200);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/head%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EMethod%20One%3C/h1%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EDefined%20variables%20globally%20and%20assign%20then%20after%20the%20load%20event%20is%20fired%3C/p%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccanvas%20id=%22myCanvas%22%20width=%22400%22%20height=%22400%22%3E%3C/canvas%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/body%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/html%3E%20%20**2)**%20The%20second%20method%20would%20be%20to%20put%20the%20script%20block%20after%20the%20canvas%20element%20so%20that%20it%20is%20already%20loaded%20in%20the%20[DOM][2]%20when%20your%20javascript%20tries%20to%20access%20it.%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Chtml%20lang=%22en%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EOnload%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/head%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EMethod%20Two%3C/h1%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EPut%20the%20script%20after%20the%20DOM%20element%20you%20wish%20to%20access%3C/p%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccanvas%20id=%22myCanvas%22%20width=%22400%22%20height=%22400%22%3E%3C/canvas%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20background%20=%20new%20Image();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background.src%20=%20%22img/map.jpg%22;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20canvas%20=%20document.getElementById(%22myCanvas%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20ctx%20=%20canvas.getContext(%222d%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.onload%20=%20function()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ctx.drawImage(background,%200,%200);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/body%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/html%3E%20%20I've%20used%20the%20new%20%60const%60%20and%20%60let%60%20keywords%20just%20to%20highlight%20the%20difference%20between%20these%20two%20approaches,%20although%20using%20%60var%60%20instead%20will%20work%20fine%20too.%20(see%20[let][3]%20and%20[const][4])%20%20If%20you%20want%20to%20[avoid%20global%20variables][5]%20then%20you%20might%20structure%20your%20code%20like%20this%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Chtml%20lang=%22en%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Chead%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20charset=%22UTF-8%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width,%20initial-scale=1.0%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cmeta%20http-equiv=%22X-UA-Compatible%22%20content=%22ie=edge%22%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctitle%3EOnload%3C/title%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cscript%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20background%20=%20new%20Image();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20background.src%20=%20%22img/map.jpg%22;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20draw%20=%20context%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20context.drawImage(background,%200,%200);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.addEventListener('load',%20()%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20canvas%20=%20document.querySelector(%22#myCanvas%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20ctx%20=%20canvas.getContext(%222d%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20draw(ctx);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C/script%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/head%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EFinal%3C/h1%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EAdd%20an%20event%20listener%3C/p%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ccanvas%20id=%22myCanvas%22%20width=%22400%22%20height=%22400%22%3E%3C/canvas%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/body%3E%20%20%20%20%20%3C/html%3E%20%20It%20doesn't%20matter%20that%20I'm%20using%20[arrow%20functions][6],%20or%20[querySelector][7],%20I%20just%20prefer%20these%20newer%20methods.%20The%20point%20is%20to%20pass%20in%20the%20canvas%20context%20to%20any%20function%20that%20needs%20it%20%60draw(ctx)%60.%20%20The%20two%20lines%20of%20code%20creating%20the%20%60Image()%60%20and%20then%20setting%20the%20background%20had%20to%20be%20done%20before%20the%20document%20had%20finished%20loading,%20presumable%20because%20you%20are%20.%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load%20%20%20[2]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model%20%20%20[3]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let%20%20%20[4]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const%20%20%20[5]:%20https://www.w3.org/wiki/JavaScript_best_practices#Avoid_globals%20%20%20[6]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions%20%20%20[7]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Onload</title>
    <script>
        draw = context => {
            const background = new Image();
            background.src = "img/map.png";
            background.addEventListener('load', () => {
                context.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
            });
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            draw(ctx);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Final</h1>
    <p>Add an event listener to the image</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```